# Working LIKE statement with % on column names but rows repeated

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have my SELECT query used with LIKE statement working but am shocked; that my rows fetched are repeated, and i don't know why?

```
SELECT *
FROM questions, counts
WHERE counts.test_coursecode LIKE '%'  || questions.coursecode || '%'
```

Comment: Can you share some data? Seems like multiple `coursecode`s may match a `test_coursecode` (or vise versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the inner join of the two tables

```
SELECT *
FROM questions q inner join  counts c on a q.id and c.fk
WHERE counts.test_coursecode LIKE CONCAT('%', questions.coursecode, '%')
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM questions q , counts c 
where a q.id and c.fk
and counts.test_coursecode LIKE CONCAT('%', questions.coursecode, '%')
```

Comment: the q.id and c.fk help put an end to the repeated rows thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use

```
SELECT *
FROM questions, counts
WHERE counts.test_coursecode LIKE CONCAT('%', questions.coursecode, '%')
```

instead.

`||` is not the concatenation operator but the [logical OR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) in the sql dialect of MySQL.

Your query will match every row, because any value will match the first expression, it evaluates to

```
SELECT *
FROM questions, counts
WHERE counts.test_coursecode LIKE '%'  -- that's true, if test_course_code is not null
    OR questions.coursecode 
    OR '%'
```

Comment: i just tried yours@VMai it works but rows also repeated.

Comment: @PULabs If we have no data and no desired result, we can't help better.

Comment: Amazingly it still works but row kept on been repeated... thanks for your valuable time @VMail

Comment: @PULabs As user1261620 mentioned: maybe you need another join condition too.

Comment: Special thanks to @VMai, you just so brainy i wish you could check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820936/complex-limit-rows-query